# C# - How do you display Apr '11 with DateTime.ToString

Tags: c#, .net

Ok I've tried everything to render a date in the *Apr '11* format with the `DateTime ToString` method.  The documentation says `'` is reserved for a string literal, so I would think to display a single apostrophe I'd use `'''` - However, no go.  Here's what I've tried so far:

```
taskdata.Month.Start.ToString("MMM 'yy")
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
taskdata.Month.Start.ToString("MMM ''yy")
"Apr 09"
taskdata.Month.Start.ToString("MMM '''yy")
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
taskdata.Month.Start.ToString("MMM ''''yy")
"Apr 09"
taskdata.Month.Start.ToString("MMM \'yy")
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
taskdata.Month.Start.ToString("MMM '\''yy")
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Seriously what's the secret?  I refuse to concatenate!

Comment: *I refuse to concatenate!* and why not?  Why waste time on something you could just implement yourself and be done with?

Comment: You ever inherited code and gone "Uh why did they do it like that instead of the easy way, obviously that person can't code."  Yea, I don't want to be "that person" in the future.

Comment: @EdS. To write a better code. To learn new things. To achieve a challenge (hmm, by asking others, fail :).

Comment: Hey I'd have figured it out eventually..  probably.

Comment: @Otiel: Agreed.  I didn't realize that it was a simply character escape issue, read too quickly.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to escape (double escape, actually):

```
new DateTime(2011, 10, 1).ToString("MMM \\'yy")
```

Comment: Note that if you use a verbatim string literal you don't need the double escaping: `@"MMM \'yy"`.

Answer (score 10):

```
String.Format(@"{0:MMM  \'yy}", DateTime.Now)
```

Worked for me